# Building a Complete Check Box Node Tree

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, jtree

My objective is to build a check box node tree with the following features .

Nodes :
            There will be 2 types of nodes all over the tree .

1 . Parent Nodes

2 . Child Nodes

All the nodes are check box nodes .
The parent nodes need to have an additional folder like icon , in addition to the check box.

And all the check boxes must be editable
More than one check box must be checkable at a time .

What is the best possible approach that i can take ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JTree with checkboxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223188/jtree-with-checkboxes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks similar to this Stack Overflow result:
[JTree with checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223188/jtree-with-checkboxes)

Which refers to this example: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/CheckBoxNodeTreeSample.htm

In this latter example, change nonLeafRenderer to return your new component (a folder with a checkbox, possibly in a JPanel.)

Comment: If i render the non leaf node with a separate renderer , how wil i be able to edit it ?

Comment: [This blog post](http://www.jroller.com/santhosh/date/20050610) has some criticisms and fixes for the Java2s solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a ready to go component you can use [CheckBoxTree](http://www.jidesoft.com/javadoc/com/jidesoft/swing/CheckBoxTree.html) from [Jide-oss](http://java.net/projects/jide-oss/).